# Asynchronously updating a graph?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, graph

I am playing around with an idea in C#, and would like some advice on the best way to go about asynchronously updating a large number of nodes in a graph. I haven't read anything about how to do things like that, everything I've seen in textbooks / examples use graphs whose nodes don't really change.

Suppose I have a graph of some large number of nodes (thousands). Each node has some internal state that depends on some public properties of each of its neighbors, as well as potentially some external input.

So schematically a node is simply:

```
class Node
{
    State internalState;
    public State exposedState;

    Input input;
    List<Node> neigbors;        

    void Update()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            DoCalculations(input, internalState, neighbors);
            exposedState = ExposedState(internalState);
        }
    }

    State ExposedState(State state) { ... }
    void DoCalculations() { ... }
}
```

The difficulty is that I would like nodes to be updated as soon as either their their input state changes (by subscribing to an event or polling) or their neighbor's state changes. If I try to do this synchronously in the naive way, I have the obvious problem:

```
Node A updates when input changes
Its neighbor B sees A has changed, updates.
Node A sees its neighbor B has changed, updates
B updates
A updates
....
Stack overflows
```

If I update by instead, enumerating through all nodes and calling their update methods, nodes may be inconsistently updated (e.g.: A's input changes, B updates and doesn't see A's change, A updates and changes exposed state).

I could update by trying to maintain a stack of nodes who want to be updated first, but then their neighbors need to be updated next, and theirs next, etc, which means each update cycle I would need to carefully walk the graph and determine the right update order, which could be very slow...

The naive asynchronous way is to have each node in its own thread (or more simply, an initial asynchronous method call happens to each node's update method, which updates indefinitely in a while(true){...}). The problem with his is that having thousands of threads does not seem like a good idea!

It seems like this should have a simple solution; this isn't too different from cellular automata, but any synchronous solution I come up with either has to update a large number of times compared to the number of nodes to get a message from one end to the other, or solving some kind of complicated graph-walking problem with multiple starting points.

The async method seems trivially simple, if only I could have thousands of threads...

So what is the best way to go about doing something like this?

Comment: So does it mean that every node change affects (indirectly) all other nodes?

Comment: Yes, it does. Conceivably a node could choose to pass along state in its exposed state, but not keep it in its external state to allow "passing along" of messages to nodes that know to listen for them.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that Rx ([The Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985%28VS.103%29.aspx)) would be a good starting point.

Each piece of state that other nodes might need to depend on is exposed as an `IObserable<TState>` and other nodes can then subscribe to those observables:

```
otherNode.PieceOfState.SubScribe(v => { UpdateMyState(v) });
```

Rx provides lots of filtering and processing functions for observables: these can be used to filter duplicate events (but you'll need to define "duplicate" of course).

Here's an introductory article: http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2009/10/14/introducing-the-reactive-framework-part-i.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure your updates converge. This has nothing to do with how you perform them (synchronously, asynchronously, serially or in parallel).

Suppose you have two nodes A and B, that are connection. A changes, triggering a recalculation of B. B then changes, triggering a recalculation of A. If the recalculation of A changes A's value, it will trigger a recalculation of B and so on. You need this sequence of triggers to stop at one point - you need your changes to converge. If they don't, no technique you use can fix it.

Once you are sure the calculations converge and you don't get into endless recalculations you should start with the simple single-threaded synchronous calculation and see if it performs well. If it's fast enough, stop there. If not, you can try to parallelize it.

I wouldn't create a thread per calculation, it doesn't scale at all. Instead use a queue of the calculations that need to be performed, and each time you *change the value of node A*, put all its neighbors in the queue. You can have a few threads processing the queue, making it a much more scalable architecture.

If this *still* isn't fast enough, you'll need to optimize what you put in the queue and how you handle it. I think it's way too early to worry about that now.